# How to access parent window variables from object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xhtml

I've got an XHTML 1.1 Strict document that is loading another XHTML 1.1 document in an `<object>` element (*as `<iframe>` isn't part of the XHTML 1.1 spec*).  I'm having trouble in IE8 (don't care about 6 or 7) with accessing a javascript variable, `Lightbox`, in the parent window, from the document loaded in the `<object>`.

In Firefox and everywhere I've seen online, I can just use `window.parent.Lightbox`.  In IE8 however, I get it being undefined.  `window.parent` does give me an object but it doesn't have my `Lightbox` variable.  I've also tried `window.Lightbox`, `window.top.Lightbox`, and `window.top.document.Lightbox`, but all return `undefined`.

I should mention I'm using Javascript to set the `data` property of the `<object>` - but I don't see how that could affect anything relevant.

What Javascript Fu do I need to do to be able to access my `Lightbox` variable?

Comment: First of all, why are you using XHTML, and especially strict?  XHTML is in reality a deprecated standard, which has no benefits except if you are planning to extend it with things like MathML

Comment: How is XHTML deprecated?  There is not a more recent published standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to a HTML doctype, or even XHTML Transitional.
Using the object tag has absolutely no benefits.

Comment: Ya, I think I will.  I wanted to keep everything 1.1 Strict, but it's becoming such a pain in the butt that it's not worth it.

Comment: If you have no particular requirements, go for '<!DOCTYPE html>' which is the new HTML5 doctype. And of course, use validation :)